# How to Change the Background Color of login page in Bootstrap AdminLTE 3 theme

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, less, node-sass

I have tried to change adminlte.css elements as per my requirement but color of the background page and my required changes are not changed.

I am new to SASS. What are the steps to change the color and size of the pre-defined login page in Bootstrap ADMINLTE 3 theme

Answer (score 0):

I've just met the same problem.

I think, by default, the HTML pages of AdminLTE use the file `dist/css/adminlte.min.css` and not the file `dist/css/adminlte.css`. You can confirm it by :

1. Running your server from the terminal (`python manage.py runserver`).
2. Displaying the wanted page on a browser.
3. Reading the terminal.

There should have something like `GET /static/dist/css/adminlte.min.css.map` that confirms it's the file `dist/css/adminlte.min.css` and not the file `dist/css/adminlte.css` which is used.

So, in the HTML pages, you can replace  :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">`

by

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/dist/css/adminlte.css">`

then, when you launch the wanted page, it should use the `adminlte.css` file that you edited.